# JavaScript Closure Part Something

Tags: javascript

Hello how are you? I'm Steve.

I have found and read the sentence which is quoted below.

> [In programming languages having first-class functions, closures (that are also called function closures or lexical closures) are a technique for implementing lexically-scoped name binding. Concerning its operation, a closure is nothing but a data structure storing a function together with an environment, which maps all associating each free variable of the function (that are used locally, but defined in an enclosing scope) with the value or storage location the name was bound to at the time the closure was created.](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/JavaScript/Closures#JavaScript_closures)

Does someone make sense of "... maps all associating each free variable of the function ... "? I would think the portion of the sentence should read "... maps all associating and each free variable of the function ... " I was grateful of any input.

Thank you

Steve

Comment: [English Language & Usage](http://english.stackexchange.com/) ?

Comment: I don't think this is a strictly programming question, even if it asks after a programming term. Weirdly, this belongs more on [English Language and Usage](http://english.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: The phrasing is indeed markedly off and looks like a combination of ESL and multiple authors editing each other's text. Probably should be *"...which maps each free variable of the function...to the value or storage location..."* or *"...which associates each free variable of the function...with the value or storage location..."* or similar.

Comment: There is a thing in there which associates each free variable of the function with the value or storage locations the variables were bound to at the time the closure was created. The sentence in wiki appears garbled to me. "Map" (as a verb) and "associate" seem to be two different words for the same thing, and somebody accidentally left both in when he meant to change from one to the other. Inserting an "and" where you did does not help.

Comment: I've come across this years ago and nothing has been being altered since then. I would say. However this time I simply had to ask someone making sure that I'm not stupid. Anyway this site wasn't probably such a good source at all. Many thanks you guys Steve